# echo a file with a certain extension (php)

Tags: php, cakephp, echo, cakephp-3.0

First of all, I'm not a developer.
I'm frontend guy with some basic php knowledge.

I'm writing a little code to get a banner that's hooked up to a profile.
I'm as far as getting the complete path including the current user id.

But the trick now is getting any file in a specific map that has an image extension (either jpg, jpeg, png or gif).
I've searched a lot but it looks like the only option is to specify the file upfront, which would be impossible for me since the file is from a specific user.

My current string looks like this:

```
<div class="headerContainer" style="background-image:url(<?php echo ('/data/profiles/banner/'); ?><?php echo $this->Session->read == $item['user']; ?><?php echo ('/'); ?>)">
```

I hope someone can help me cause I'm all out of ideas.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should start reading the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html) of the framework you are working with... Your question does not provide enough information to give a good answer... You're trying to get data from a session variable, but gave no info about the structure. Also in CakePHP 3 you're usually working with objects and not arrays... How is your controller code looking like where you are setting the session data? What exactly should the result look like?... too many open questions...

Comment: Are you trying to read a variable or session data because "echo $this->Session->read == $item['user'];" is incorrect syntax. Session is used as: $this->Session->read('Variable');